# How to decrease tension on Everbilt Spring Tee Hinge?

Tags: hinges, gates

I accidentally tightened the hinge (maybe 3-4 times) before installing the darn thing on the gate.

Now i have a self-closing hinge that is way too tight!

The instructions mention how to decrease the tension, but i cant figure it out!

Instructions:
 "To decrease tension, close gate and depress wrench to disengage ratchet. Rotate wrench counter-clockwise."

[image]

Now, i know how to follow directions, i think. Do i need to install the hinge to the gate first? i tried manually extending the hinge so that it is straight (as if the gate was completely closed). But this is not helping. The wrench doesnt turn counter-clockwise at all.

Please help!

*** Resolved ***

I finally got it working. I had to depress (push) firmly with quite a bit of force. I used the 2nd hinge to test out the loosening. I jut had to apply alot of force (use the floor to push in the wrench).

Comment: Did you depress the wrench? The instructions would indicate that it is necessary to push down on the wrench to disengage an internal cog of sorts.

Comment: i pushed down using the wrench. Nothing happens. The wrench either goes in (so you can turn it) or it goes out. There is no indication of what should happen if it is depressed properly.

Comment: I finally got it working. I had to depress (push) firmly with quite a bit of force.